# Search and replace a substring only if another substring is not present

Tags: shell-script, sed

I have the following strings in a very large document:

```
1.test.html#
2.test.md#
3.http://test.html#
4.https://test.md#
5.http://test.md#
6.test2.md#
```

Now I want to replace every `.md#` with `.html#` but ONLY if there is no `http` in the string. So only 2 and 6 should have a replacement. How can I do this in a shell script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With GNU sed. If current line (pattern space) contains `http` jump to end of script (`b`). Otherwise do search and replace.

```
sed '/http/b; s/\.md#/.html#/' file
```

Output:

```
1.test.html#
2.test.html#
3.http://test.html#
4.https://test.md#
5.http://test.md#
6.test2.html#
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

---

See: `man sed`

Comment: Very good solution.  Just as an alternative: `sed '/http/! s/\.md#/.html#/' file`

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -pe'/http/ or s/\.md#/.html#/' input.txt > output.txt
perl -pe'/http/||s/\.md#/.html#/' input.txt > output.txt   #same
perl -i -pe'/http/||s/\.md#/.html#/' file.txt              #edit inplace, changes file.txt
perl -i.bk -pe'/http/||s/\.md#/.html#/' files*.txt         #same with backups to .bk files
```

`sed` and `awk` are great, but `perl` has everything they have and very much more.