# add suffix to certain text lines if and only if the suffix is not present

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am trying to do something like this:

```
sed -i.bak '/^startswith/ s/$/endswith/' /path/to/file
```

But *only* for lines that do **not** already end with the string "endswith".

In words, I want to find lines that start with some text and that do **not** end with some other text and then append my desired text at the end of that line.

I am currently referring to [Search and replace a substring only if another substring is not present](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533784/search-and-replace-a-substring-only-if-another-substring-is-not-present) and the `sed` man page, but I am not sure if I'm on the right track.

Comment: If you provide concise, testable sample input/output then we could test potential solutions before posting them.

Answer (score 2):

The following approach works:

```
sed -i.bak '/endswith/b; /^startswith/ s/$/endswith/' /path/to/file
```

I'm not sure if it is the most efficient solution, however.

Comment: I think that's not bad at all; it will probably run more or less as fast as the equivalent alternatives `/endswith$/!{/^startswith/s/$/endswith/;}` and `/endswith$/!s/^startswith.*/&endswith/`.

Comment: @Quasímodo - thank you. If you wish to add your solution with a good explanation as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly:

```
sed '/^startswith/s/endswith$//; /^startswith/s/$/endswith/' /path/to/file
```

From the left to the right:
`/^startswith`   - find all lines that start with *'startswith'*,
`s/endswith$//`  - basically remove trailing/suffix *'endswith'*,
`/^startswith`   - find me again all lines that start with *'startswith'*,
`s/$/endswith/`  - at this point all *'^startswith'* lines are without 'endswith' at the end, so just add it.

Comment: Thank you. Looks a bit inefficient, but I learned from it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk:

```
awk '/^startswith/{ sub(/(endswith)?$/,"endswith") } 1' /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -pe 's/ (^^ header \s .* $$) /$0 trailer/ unless /trailer $$/;'
```

Sample Input:

```
header 0123456789
header 0123456789 trailer
none   0123456789 trailer
none   0123456789
```

Sample Output:

```
header 0123456789 trailer
header 0123456789 trailer
none   0123456789 trailer
none   0123456789
```

https://docs.raku.org/syntax/s$SOLIDUS$SOLIDUS$SOLIDUS
https://raku.org